# Who has the higher hand: 44 vs. A2 on a JJKK2 board?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand

I played with my friends yesterday and run into the following situation:

player 1: **4 4**

player 2: **A 2**

table: **J J K K 2**

Both players have two pairs: **J J K K**.

However, player 1 have one pair in hand. Does that count? I think player 2 wins because of higher card in hand, but the rulebook I have is not clear about this.

Comment: The popular term for this situation is called "counterfeited": something which has value suddenly has no value due to the board making a better hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Player 2 wins, best 5-card hand rule: JJKKA

Comment: Shouldn't it be KKJJA, with the higher pair listed first?

Comment: @corsiKa I don't think this matters, it's self-preference, as long as the idea is conveyed.

Answer (score 8):

The highest 5 card hand, JJKKA beats JJKK4. The second four "doesn't play" because the pair of fours was superseded by TWO higher pairs. For the same reason, the two in player one's hand that creates a "matched pair" with the board, doesn't play.